# How to solve CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 502 when using cloudinary in nextjs 13?

Tags: next.js13, cloudinary

I am getting Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/codestacks/image/upload. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 502 in nextjs 13 when using cloudinary to upload image on it.

I used

```
const data = new FormData();
            data.append('file', image);
            data.append('upload_preset', 'CodeStacksProfileImages');
            data.append('cloud_name', 'codestacks');
            data.append('folder', 'CodeStacksProfileImages');

            let imageUrl;
            const uploadImagePromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
                const response = fetch('https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/codestacks/image/upload', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                    },
                    body: data,
                });
                resolve(response);
            });
```

but got following error:
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/codestacks/image/upload. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 502.

First I was using axios and it was working well but when I switched to fecth, it gave the error.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use withCredentials if you used axios you can set defaults in App.js file. I mean you have to send your request from front to backend by withCredentials= true

```
 axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

for fetch:

```
   fetch('your url', {
   credentials: 'include',
  })
```

and change your setting file in backend set front server in CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST part in backend

```
 CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    'https://ec2-ip/login',
   'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
    'your frontend local host url'
  ]
```

Comment: Oh, I have already mentioned that I am using fetch not axios.

Comment: oh sorry for fetch you can use : fetch('your url ', {
  credentials: 'include',
})